# Hibernate save collection

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm using Hibernate 4 (with Spring) to persist my object into database.
I have some issue when I try save parent with a collection children.

My Table:

```
| A | => PK (Composite) [String + Integer]
| B | => PK (Composite) [Stirng + Integer] + Integer
```

Naturaly the PK of B is composite with same PK of A and A contain a collection of B.

In my code I want:

```
A parent = new A();
parent.addCollection(new B());
parentDao.create(parent)
```

When Hibernate persit the object it can set a String into A PK and calculate the max + 1 for Inter.
Same way for B PK, Hibernate set the same PK value from A (parent => child) and calculate the max + 1 for the second Intenger.

It's possible?
Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

My Class:

```
Class A {
    static Class A_PK {
      private String codAzienda;
      private Integer year;
      ... Get, Set, HashCode, Equals and toString() ...
    }

   private A_PK id;

   ... another columns ...

   @OneToMany(cascade=ALL)
   @JoinColumns({
      @JoinColumn(name="cod_azienda"),
      @JoinColumn(name="year")
   })
   List<B> children;
}

Class B {
   static Class B_PK {
       private String codAzienda;
       private Integer year;
       private Integer nextId;
       ... Get, Set, HashCode, Equals and toString() ...
   }

 @EmbeddedId
@AttributeOverrides({
   @AttributeOverride(name = "codAzienda", column = @Column(name = "cod_azienda")),
   @AttributeOverride(name = "codCliente", column = @Column(name = "cod_cliente"))
})

   private B_PK id;
   ... another columns ...
}
```

Comment: Yes it is possible but what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried use custom saveOrUpdate event listener, use a Interceptor and AOP from my DAO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following :

**A.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_A")
public class A implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "STR_ID")
    private String strId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "INT_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Integer intId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "a")
    private List<B> bs;

    public A(String strId) {
        this.strId = strId;
    }

    public void addB(B b) {
        if (bs == null) {
            bs = new ArrayList<B>();
        }
        b.setA(this);
        bs.add(b);
    }
}
```

**B.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_B")
public class B implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "INT_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Integer intId;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "A_STR_FK", referencedColumnName = "STR_ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "A_INT_FK", referencedColumnName = "INT_ID")
    })
    private A a;

    void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.

In my case B become:
`public class B {
   private String strId;  // A foreign key
   private Integer intId; // A foreign key
   private Integer intIdB;
}`

Comment: The composite foreign key for A is automatically created by Hibernate and since I annotated the ManyToOne mapping with @Id, the fields of this foreign key will also be used in the composite primary key of B.

Comment: Great! Your code work fine. But If I want save only B I need create B and create A for set primary key! I don't know why Hibernate cant set the reference (@OneToMany parent to child) if the field is a composite-id (@EmebedId annotation)

Comment: If the primary key of B includes the foreign key of A then an instance of B should never exist without an instance of A! If that's really what you want then your datamodel is not logical and you should perhaps use different columns for the primary key of B and the foreign key of A (even if they contain the same value)